# GL_LINES not showing up on top of cube?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to create a 3d Rubiks Cube with OpenGL and Pygame.  However I when I try to draw lines on top of the `GL_QUADS` surfaces I have created, they don't show up.

I have tried putting the `GL_LINES` after the `GL_QUADS` line but it they still do not show up as black lines.

Does anyone have a solution?  Also, how would I adjust the thickness of the lines?

This is what the code looks like:

```py
def draw(self):
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3fv((0, 0, 0))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))

    glColor3fv((0, 0, 0))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))

    glColor3fv((0, 0, 0))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))

    glColor3fv((0, 0, 0))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_QUADS)

    glColor3fv(colors[0])
    # fix z
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))

    glColor3fv(colors[1])
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len))

    # fix x
    glColor3fv(colors[2])
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len))

    glColor3fv(colors[3])
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len))

    # fix y
    glColor3fv(colors[4])
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len))

    glColor3fv(colors[5])
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len))
    glVertex3fv((self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len))

    glEnd()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines are covered by the polygons. Note, the lines and the polygons mathematically have the same depth, but in fact this is depending on floating-point arithmetic precision either the fragment which is drawn by the polygon or by the line "wins" the [depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test). This may also cause [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

Slightly push the polygons back, by setting a depth offset (see [`glPolygonOffset`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonOffset.xhtml)), so the lines will be in front of the polygons:

```py
 def draw(self):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) 

        glBegin(GL_LINES)
        # [...]
        glEnd()

        glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL )
        glPolygonOffset( 1.0, 1.0 )

        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        # [...]
        glEnd()

        glDisable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL )
```

If you still cant see the line, then you've to increase the polygon offset (1st parameter). Note the lines are thin and drawn in black (`glColor3fv((0, 0, 0))`), possibly they are hardly to see.

---

The thickness of a line can be set by [`glLineWidth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLineWidth.xhtml)

---

Note, a cube consists of 8 vertices, 6 sides and 12 edges. In your code you draw only 4 edges.
I recommend to define a list of the 8 corner points of the cube and to define a list of the 6 side quad indices and the 12 edges. Use this lists to draw the cube:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-opengl-cube-wireframe](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/pygame-opengl-cube-wireframe#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
class Cube:
  
  def __init__(self, x, y, z, len):
     self.x = x
     self.y = y
     self.z = z
     self.len = len

     self.v = [
       (self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len),
       (self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z - self.len),
       (self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len),
       (self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z - self.len),
       (self.x - self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len),
       (self.x + self.len, self.y - self.len, self.z + self.len),
       (self.x + self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len),
       (self.x - self.len, self.y + self.len, self.z + self.len),
     ]
     self.edges = [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (4,5), (5,6),
                   (6,7), (7,4), (0,4), (1,5), (2,6), (3,7)]
     self.surfaces = [(0,1,2,3), (5,4,7,6), (4,0,3,7),(1,5,6,2), (4,5,1,0), (3,2,6,7)]

     self.colors = [(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (1,0.5,0)]

  def draw(self):
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    glLineWidth(5)
    glColor3fv((0, 0, 0))
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for e in self.edges:
        glVertex3fv(self.v[e[0]])
        glVertex3fv(self.v[e[1]])
    glEnd()

    glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL )
    glPolygonOffset( 1.0, 1.0 )

    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for i, quad in enumerate(self.surfaces):
        glColor3fv(self.colors[i])
        for iv in quad:
            glVertex3fv(self.v[iv])
    glEnd()

    glDisable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL )
```